# Unreachable code android

Tags: android

I am programming this whole day and now i am stuck with unreachable after return; at

```
return;
Recipe093.path[1] = localCursor.getString(1);
```

If i remove return i get unreachable code after continue;
Why do I get unreachable code?
Hope someone can help me and Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.musiclist);
    final Cursor localCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, (String[])null, null, (String[])null, null);
    String[] arrayOfString1 = localCursor.getColumnNames();
    int i = arrayOfString1.length;
    for (int j = 0; ; j++)
    {
      if (j >= i)
      {
        String[] arrayOfString2 = { "title", "artist", "duration" };
        int[] arrayOfInt = { 2131099668, 2131099669, 2131099670 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter localSimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 2130903044, localCursor, arrayOfString2, arrayOfInt);
        localSimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new AudioListViewBinder());
        ListView localListView = (ListView)findViewById(2131099667);
        localListView.setAdapter(localSimpleCursorAdapter);
        Log.d("test", "start list()");
        localListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAnonymousAdapterView, View paramAnonymousView, int paramAnonymousInt, long paramAnonymousLong)
          {
            switch (Recipe093.this.getIntent().getIntExtra("case1", 0))
            {
            default:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
            case 16:
            }
            while (true)
            {
              Intent localIntent = new Intent(Recipe093.this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
              Recipe093.this.startActivity(localIntent);
              return;
              Recipe093.path[1] = localCursor.getString(1);
              SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor10 = Recipe093.this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", 3).edit();
              localEditor10.putString("userChoice", Recipe093.path[1]);
              localEditor10.commit();
              continue;
              Recipe093.path[2] = localCursor.getString(1);
              SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor9 = Recipe093.this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", 3).edit();
              localEditor9.putString("userChoice1", Recipe093.path[2]);
              localEditor9.commit();
            } 
          }
        });
        return;
      }
      Log.d("Recipe093", arrayOfString1[j]);
    }
  }

  private class AudioListViewBinder
    implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder
  {
    private AudioListViewBinder()
    {
    }

    public boolean setViewValue(View paramView, Cursor paramCursor, int paramInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          int i = paramCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
          int j = paramCursor.getColumnIndex("artist");
          int k = paramCursor.getColumnIndex("duration");
          if ((paramInt == i) || (paramInt == j))
            ((TextView)paramView).setText(paramCursor.getString(paramInt));
        return false;
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: The real question is what do you want to do? Are you trying to wait for a result from this new Activity?

Comment: Thanks for help and yes i am trying to wait for result

Comment: In that case you need to launch MainActivity with `startActivityForResult()` and then retrieve the result in `onActivitResult()`. The concept is rather simple, but you will need to reorder your code. (But you have to change your code around anyways to make it run :)

Comment: I am trying to get path of the file that i chose on audio listview and then use it for soundpool at MainActivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, `return;` means "exit this method now". So anything after a return statement is not run.

You can use scope to have multiple returns:

```
if(x == 1) {
    return;
    // Nothing will be called here on down in this scope, i.e. before `}`
}
x = 1;
return; 
// Nothing will be called here on down
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can `return;` the code stops and returns to the first method. It will not run any code after this line. The same story with `break;`

Answer (score 1):

As Sam said (you should accept his answer), `return` means exit now.

However, `return` for a method which returns void is optional, since the closing brace for the method will also return:

These are equivalent:

```
void someMethod(){
    doSomeStuff();
    return;
}

void someMethod(){
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

It is considered bad practice to use `return` in a void method unless you want to return early but, any explicit return must be conditional, i.e. part of a `switch` or `if` statement.  If they are not conditional, then the compiler knows that the method will always exit at that point and any code after it cannot possibly execute, hence the compiler error you are seeing.

To most Java coders, the first example just looks wrong.

PS.  `while(true)` is horrible but, if you want to get out of that loop early, you should use `break` which will transfer execution to the statement after the end of the while loop, not `return`.